# Comparing Numpy arrays like bit mask

Tags: python, numpy

I want to compare numpy array two `scale` and `data`

for exaple

```
scale = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0] first and fifth and ninth bit is 1

data1 = [8,2,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0] -> NG, because fifth bit is `0`
data2 = [8,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0] -> OK, because first ,fifth, ninth bit is more than 0
```

What I want to check is

Every positions where `scale` is `1` should be more than `0` in `data`

Is there any good numpy function to do this??

Comment: why not compare scale to (data2>0)? if (scale == (data2>0)).all(): print('OK'); else: print('NG')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step using `Numpy`:

1. Convert to boolean, will return true when value > 0
2. Bitwise AND
3. Check equality

```
import numpy as np

scale = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
data1 = [8,2,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]
data2 = [8,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]

scale= np.array(scale, dtype=bool)
data1= np.array(data1, dtype=bool)
data2= np.array(data2, dtype=bool)

and1 = np.bitwise_and(scale, data1)
and2 = np.bitwise_and(scale, data2)

is_match1 = np.array_equal(scale, and1)
is_match2 = np.array_equal(scale, and2)

print(is_match1) # False
print(is_match2) # True
```

Comment: Thank you bitwise_and is quite new to me. and very helpful